# How to pass through SSL traffic on nginx based on SNI?

Tags: nginx

In my current nginx configuration, I have multiple

```
server {
  listen *:443;
  servername my_server_name;
  ...
}
```

blocks. These blocks are managed by third party software and cannot be changed by me.

I can easily add another domain which is ssl-terminated by nginx by adding another block.

However, I would like to add a domain which is not ssl-terminated on this nginx server, but passed through to another host, which does the ssl termination. It should be SNI-detected, just like the other `server_name` configurations.

I thought of something like:

```
server {
    listen *:443;
    server_name my_project.org;
    proxy_pass 10.1.1.3:443;
}
```

However, this results in a `proxy_pass is not allowed here` error.

I have read about the [stream module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) and [stream ssl preread module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html), but couldn't really figure out how to combine this with existing (non-changeable) nginx server-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass tells that `proxy_pass` is allowed in `location`, `if in location` and `limit_except` sections.

However, if you use `server` block with TLS, the `server` always terminates TLS.

In order to pass TLS through, you need to use the `stream` module.